# How to mask each character in an input after keydown event?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a credit card validation that uses inputs to enter the credit card number. I would like to mask each digit entered with a "#" after a user presses a key e.g typing 1 would replace the 1 with a # on the input. I'm using a keydown event for my validations.

Note

I don't need the values to persist, I'm able to store the original values to an array before the change. 
The # conversion should be displayed after each key is pressed, not once the whole number is typed.

I've tried using

```
 event.target.value = "#";
```

This gives a weird output e.g #1234 instead of 1234 being replaced with ####

My latest solution

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  event.target.value(/\d/g, "#");
});
```

```html
<input size=4 placeholder="----" />
```

This doesn't do anything at all

I suspect that my thinking on how to handle this problem is fundamentally wrong. Please, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `event.target.value(/\d/g, "#")` should be `event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\d/g, "#");`. This should get you closer.

Comment: It does do something....throw an error in dev tools console. Always report errors when asking questions. Those errors are big clues as to where your problem is

Comment: Could you use a password input instead, this seems to exhibit the same behaviour you're after (apart from the making character)

Comment: Why don’t you just set the field as a password field?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password

Comment: Thank you @TylerRoper. That worked. Thanks, everybody else too. I couldn't use a password field because the requirement was for a type="text" field. charliefl The console didn't log any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event.target.value(/\d/g, "#") should be event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\d/g, "#");. This should get you closer. – Tyler Roper

Answer (score 0):

Rather bind event on key up, so it also converts last entered value.

**Code:**

```
(function () {

            const input = document.querySelector("input");
            input.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
                var maskedVal = event.target.value.replace(/\d/g, "#");
                event.target.value= maskedVal;
                console.log("#########",maskedVal);
            });


        })();
```